# Can I move a keg that has been lagering?

Tags: lagering

Let's say I've been lagering a keg for a good couple of months. The cold has cause all the precipitate to settle at the bottom of the keg and I've got crystal clear beer!

What happens if I move this keg to my kegerator and jostle it around a bit? Am I going to essentially lose months of lagering time because I shook it and mixed all the precipitate back into the beer?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't tip it over you'll be fine. Waves on top of the beer will not get to the bottom.